# Matching data in two different tables (compare data)

Tags: sql, oracle

I have problem while matching data from 2 different tables. 
example 
table1: a,b,c,d,e (col)
table2: a,d,e,f,g (col)

How to match data in table1 col a,d,e with table2 col a,d,e
in condition if row in table1 matched with row in table2 then stop looping?

In my script result always make duplicate while matching data (when data in table1 matched its still looping not locked with the other data in table2).

```
select distinct x.a, y.a, x.d, y.d, x.e, y.e 
from table1 x,
     table2 y
where x.a = y.a(+) and x.d = y.d(+) and x.e = y.e(+)
```

sorry for my bad english...

**Edit:**

sorry i cant type well using smartphone..
maybe like this..

table1

```
col a--b--c--d--e
1st_row 'Ryan'--'Sofia'--'Bulgaria'--'January'--'107'
2nd_row 'Dony'--'Vienna'--'Austria'--'March'--'103'
3rd_row 'Ryan'--'Berlin'--'Germany'--'January'--'107'
4th_row 'Dony'--'Milan'--'Italy'--'March'--'103'
```

table2

```
col a--d--e--f--g
1st_row 'Ryan'--'January'--'107'--'Travel'--'5'
2nd_row 'Ryan'--'January'--'107'--'Bussiness'--'4'
3rd_row 'Dony'--'March'--'103'--'Bussiness'--'9'
4th_row 'Dony'--'March'--'103'--'Bussiness'--'3'
```

in my query

```
select distinct x.a, y.a, x.d, y.d, x.e, y.e
from table1 x,
     table2 y
where x.a = y.a(+) and x.d = y.d(+) and x.e = y.e(+)
```

result are

```
table1 1st_row matched with table2 1st_row
table1 2nd_row matched with table2 3rd_row
table1 3rd_row matched with table2 1st_row (match duplicated)
table1 4th_row matched with table2 3rd_row (match duplicated)
```

but my wanted result are
table1 1st_row matched with table2 1st_row
table1 2nd_row matched with table2 3rd_row
table1 3rd_row matched with table2 2nd_row
table1 4th_row matched with table2 4th_row

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as well formatted text.

Comment: jarlh please check my sample data and expected result at my answered post,thx

Answer (score 0):

You can use below query

```
select distinct x.a, y.a, x.d, y.d, x.e, y.e 
from table1 x
inner join table2 y
on (x.a = y.a(+) and x.d = y.d(+) and x.e = y.e(+));
```

Comment: thanx jim, tommorow i will try your query at office

Answer (score 0):

sorry i cant type well using smartphone..

maybe like this..

table1

col a--b--c--d--e

1st_row 'Ryan'--'Sofia'--'Bulgaria'--'January'--'107'

2nd_row 'Dony'--'Vienna'--'Austria'--'March'--'103'

3rd_row 
'Ryan'--'Berlin'--'Germany'--'January'--'107'
4th_row 'Dony'--'Milan'--'Italy'--'March'--'103'


table2 

col a--d--e--f--g

1st_row 'Ryan'--'January'--'107'--'Travel'--'5'

2nd_row 'Ryan'--'January'--'107'--'Bussiness'--'4' 

3rd_row 'Dony'--'March'--'103'--'Bussiness'--'9'

4th_row 'Dony'--'March'--'103'--'Bussiness'--'3'

in my query 

select distinct x.a, y.a, x.d, y.d, x.e, y.e 
from table1 x, table2 y 
where x.a = y.a(+) and x.d = y.d(+) and x.e = y.e(+)

result are

table1 1st_row matched with table2 1st_row

table1 2nd_row matched with table2 3rd_row

table1 3rd_row matched with table2 1st_row (match duplicated)

table1 4th_row matched with table2 3rd_row (match duplicated)


but my wanted result are

table1 1st_row matched with table2 1st_row

table1 2nd_row matched with table2 3rd_row

table1 3rd_row matched with table2 2nd_row

table1 4th_row matched with table2 4th_row